# Closures in Javascript: assigning local variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, closures

Just when I thought I understood closures...

The following code snippet:

```
function f() {
    var a = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = function () {
            var x = i;
            return x;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

var a = f();
console.log(a[0]());
console.log(a[1]());
console.log(a[2]());
```

prints out 3, 3, 3. I don't understand why. I'm copying the value of 'i' to the local variable x, so there should be three x's: x0=0, x1=1. x2=2. How are all of them reading the final value of i?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the value of `i` changes in your `for` loop, it's still the same `i` variable. You need to shadow `i` in that scope and effectively pass it by value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(x) {
        a[x] = function() {
            return x;
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: It would probably be less confusing to pick a different name for the IIFE's argument.

Comment: And if he minifies the code then this should be taken care of anyway

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is caused by each `a[i]` being, in fact, a closure. They all share the same `i`, which is evaluated when each `a[i]` is called, not when the loop executes. You need to create each closure with a separate context. For instance:

```
function f() {
    var a = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = makeClosure(i);
    }
    return a;
}
function makeClosure(i) {
    return function () {
        var x = i;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function name should be `breakClosure` instead of `makeClosure`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both solutions are correct. I personally find your way cleaner, but since my confusion was how to pass by value in an inner function, I'm going to pick Blender's answer.

Comment: @tldr - Blender's answer is essentially identical to mine. The key is to create a separate environment for each closure. The way Blender and I both suggested to do this is to create a function that returns a closure that makes use of the function's argument.

Comment: my understanding is the closure applies to inner functions. Is that incorrect? My solution was identical to yours (calling external function), but the book I'm learning Javascript from wanted to use closure on an inner function. That was the hard part for me to understand, which @blender clarified.

Comment: @tldr - To quote the excellent [Mozilla article on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures): _"A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created."_ Note that my solution also uses an inner function--the function object that is returned from `makeClosure`. The returned function references `i`, which, but for the closure, would simply go away as a variable when `makeClosure` returns.